# css not working after passing id in url in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

My CSS is not working after passing an ID in an URL in Laravel 5.6

My route

```
Route::any('productdetail/{id?}','AdminController@productdetail');
```

The ID URL

```
<a href="{{url('/productdetail/'.$item->id)}}"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
```

I am using Laravel 5

This is the script tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('/css/style.css')}}">
```

Comment: Are we supposed to reorder the words in this question to understand it? A bit of care, please, you are asking for help.

Comment: try `/css/app.css`?

Comment: still not working

Comment: console error  http://127.0.0.1:8000/productdetail/css/animate.css 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Zain You showed us the code for `style.css`, not `animate.css`. You're probably just missing an `/` somewhere.

Comment: actually all resource files not loading both js and css when i try to set url without id like {url('/productdetail')}} and route Route::any('productdetail','AdminController@productdetail');
 then its working when pass id its not work

Comment: You dont need to call `URL::asset()`. Its `url()` or `asset()`. Did you check that your `css` and `js` files are located inside the public folder? Or if not and you keep them inside the resources please check to build your `app.css` and `app.js` via webpack.

Comment: got it. now its working by doing this in resources file links.   <link rel="stylesheet" href="..//css/style.css">

Comment: sorry by doing this  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">

Answer (score 2):

This problems occurs because we are using the relative path in our blade template and the solution is so simple, We have to use only the asset function to overcome this problem.

So change your code like this:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"> </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just **use** what @demo suggested.

```
asset('/css/style.css')
```

**Or** just

```
href="/css/style.css"
```

But **never**

```
href="../css/style.css"
```

Because if you later on change your current URL from 127.0.0.1:8000/productdetail/{id} to , let's say, 127.0.0.1:8000/productdetail/something/{id}, the asset will not be loaded properly anymore.

By **using "/"** in front of a source, you are telling the browser to start looking from the base URL, which is 127.0.0.1:8000/ in your case.

By **omitting "/"** in front of a source you are telling the browser to start looking from the current URL, which would be 127.0.0.1:8000/productdetail in your case, or even 127.0.0.1:8000/productdetail/{id} when you add your ID to it.